# Why does the vertical resistor have no voltage across it?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I'm trying to calculate the resistance between A and B where each resistor between them has resistance R. According to my key, the middle, vertical, resistor has no voltage across it, and thus is negligible in the calculation. Why is this the case? How can we "see" that it will have 0 voltage?
[image]

It is stated that symmetry implies identical currents. But why would the following circuit be impossible?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this by realizing the upper and lower path are completely symmetric. Thus the current through each of them must be the same. And if the same current is flowing through resistors with the same resistance (the two diagonal ones on the left), the voltage drop across them is exactly the same. Therefore, the topmost and bottom-most corner are at the same potential, and the vertical resistor is connecting points of equal potential, resulting in no current across it.

---

In general, it's good advice to take advantage of symmetries in a problem. If a problem is symmetric under some operation (in this case, flipping the diagram upside down), the solution very often must also be symmetric under that same transformation. Be careful though, there are also cases where symmetry spontaneously breaks (phase transitions for example), but looking for symmetries is good practice.

Comment: Why does symmetric paths imply identical currents?

Comment: Which one of the identical paths do you think should carry more current?

Comment: Say, the top one. (See the edited post)

Comment: A silly question now would be, why it should be that and not exactly the reverse (the whole diagram flipped upside down).

Comment: Well, it could have been the bottom one, too. But that it could have been either one doesn't necessarily imply that this is impossible, no? To show that it is impossible, mustn't you prove that the second picture is impossible?

Comment: My point was that if there is no single one of those that should be preferred over the other, that can't be the right solution. What would make it spontaneously go into one or the other? There is nothing giving one preference over the other. For a more direct argument in this specific case, you can use Kirchhoff's voltage law on the right triangle to show that the solution you drew can't be right.

Comment: Well I specifically choose the currents so that Krichoff's law would hold. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: The second one for the voltages, aka the loop rule, not the one for currents.

Comment: What do you mean by "the right triangle"?. If I apply the loop rule starting from the top point and looping back to the same point in a triangle, I get -1/6 + 1/2 + 1/6 $\neq$ 0. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Since all the resistors are the same, their voltage drops are some constant times the current. But the sum of the voltage drops in a closed loop must always be zero.

Answer (score 1):

In your bottom diagram, let's say that the voltage at $B$ is zero, for convenience.

Let's label the top point as $x$, and the bottom point as $y$.

Ohm's law states that the voltage at $x$ must be

$$\frac{IR}{6}$$

And the voltage at $y$ must be

$$\frac{IR}{2}$$

But then this would mean that the current through the middle resistor must be

$$\frac{\frac{IR}{6}-\frac{IR}{2}}{R} = -\frac{I}{3}$$

(Negative meaning it would flow from $y$ to $x$).

Which it can't be, because our beginning assumption is that it was

$$\frac{I}{6}$$